# content overflowing from css grid

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Problem: I am having a problem with sizing images inside css grid column/rows. I essentially `object-fit: contain` the imagesinside their individual cells.

1. The image in "SPOT 4" is not filling the given space
2. If you uncomment the image in "SPOT 1", it will cover the entire grid and is not confined to its own css grid cell.

I have tried setting `max-width`, `object-fit` and others on the `video` level and `.channel-container` level with no success.

Background:  The `.parent-trap` css class is just an example height/width. This will vary, it may be the entire browser window, or it may be small so I cannot depend on any specific min/max dimensions. There are also other `.display4` in the full version that sometimes shows a single video that fills the whole grid, side by side that only shows 2 at a time etc, so any specific dimensions also tend to break individual `.display*`

```css
html,
body {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent-trap {
  height: 540px;
  width: 960px;
}

/* container for player */
.video-player {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

/* container for plaback control bar */
.container-controls {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

/* contains all the .channel-container s */
.channel-layout-container {
  display: grid;
  background: #000;
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

/****
**** FIX HERE
****/

.channel-container {}

img {}

/** THERE ARE OTHER DYNAMIC LAYOUTS, ISSUE IS SAME ON ALL */

/** display4 **/
.channel-layout-container.display4 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.channel-layout-container.display4 .channel-container:nth-child(n+5) {
  flex: none;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- try restricting various sizes -->
<div class="parent-trap">

  <!-- the classcommes that need to be transferred back over-->
  <div class="video-player">
    <div class="channel-layout-container display4">
      <div class="channel-container" style="background-color: khaki;">
        <!-- <img src="https://w.wallhaven.cc/full/3z/wallhaven-3zgz2y.png" />-->

      </div>
      <div class="channel-container" style="background-color: lavender;">
        SPOT 2
      </div>
      <div class="channel-container" style="background-color: lightcoral;">
        SPOT 3
      </div>
      <div class="channel-container" style="background-color: lightseagreen;">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/favicon.ico" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-controls">
      common controls and other info goes here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also read https://css-tricks.com/preventing-a-grid-blowout/ for a better understanding of the underlying problem. To understand this is essential when working with CSS grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up needing 3 things, I'm not entirely sure what the `min-width/height: 0` are doing to fix my issue but it works

```
        .channel-layout-container {
            min-height: 0;  /* NEW */
            min-width: 0;   /* NEW; needed for Firefox */
        }

        .channel-container {
            min-height: 0;  /* NEW */
            min-width: 0;   /* NEW; needed for Firefox */
        }

        img {
            display:block;
            width :100%;
            height:100%;
            object-fit:cover;

        }
```

```css
html,
body {
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.parent-trap {
    height: 540px;
    width: 960px;
}

/* container for player */
.video-player {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
}

/* container for plaback control bar */
.container-controls {
    height: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    background-color: red;
}

/* contains all the .channel-container s */
.channel-layout-container {
    display: grid;
    background: #000;
    background-color: blue;
    flex: 1;
    min-height: 0;  /* NEW */
    min-width: 0;   /* NEW; needed for Firefox */
}

/****
**** FIX HERE
****/

.channel-container {
    min-height: 0;  /* NEW */
    min-width: 0;   /* NEW; needed for Firefox */
}

img {
    display:block;
    width :100%;
    height:100%;
    object-fit:cover;

}

/** THERE ARE OTHER DYNAMIC LAYOUTS, ISSUE IS SAME ON ALL */

/** display4 **/
.channel-layout-container.display4 {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.channel-layout-container.display4 .channel-container:nth-child(n+5) {
    flex: none;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-trap">

    <!-- the classcommes that need to be transferred back over-->
    <div class="video-player">
        <div class="channel-layout-container display4">
            <div class="channel-container" style="background-color: khaki;">
                <img src="https://w.wallhaven.cc/full/3z/wallhaven-3zgz2y.png" />

            </div>
            <div class="channel-container" style="background-color: lavender;">
                SPOT 2
            </div>
            <div class="channel-container" style="background-color: lightcoral;">
                SPOT 3
            </div>
            <div class="channel-container" style="background-color: lightseagreen;">
                <img src="https://www.google.com/favicon.ico" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-controls">
            common controls and other info goes here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see now that changing `.parent-trap` dimensions keep the proper proportions , control bar is always available and just the displays adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 6):

Your issue results from your grid template definition.

Replace `1fr 1fr` with `repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr))`.

The reason for your problem is that `1fr` effectively means `minmax(auto, 1fr)`. `minmax` works such that if the first argument is greater than the second, the whole `minmax` expression is replaced by the first argument, so your whole definition becomes

```
grid-template-columns: auto auto;
grid-template-rows: auto auto;
```

Setting `minmax(0, 1fr)` prevents this and effectively sets what you did by setting `min-width/-height` to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

All you had to do is to add those lines (see the code below) on `img` in your css.

```css
html,
body {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.parent-trap {
  height: 540px;
  width: 960px;
}

/* container for player */
.video-player {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

/* container for plaback control bar */
.container-controls {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

/* contains all the .channel-container s */
.channel-layout-container {
  display: grid;
  background: #000;
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

/****
         **** FIX HERE
         ****/

.channel-container {
  
}

/* lines I added */
img {
  display:block;
  width :100%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
}

/** THERE ARE OTHER DYNAMIC LAYOUTS, ISSUE IS SAME ON ALL */

/** display4 **/
.channel-layout-container.display4 {
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.channel-layout-container.display4 .channel-container:nth-child(n + 5) {
  flex: none;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- try restricting various sizes -->
<div class="parent-trap">

  <!-- the classcommes that need to be transferred back over-->
  <div class="video-player">
    <div class="channel-layout-container display4">
      <div class="channel-container" style="background-color: khaki;">
        <img src="https://w.wallhaven.cc/full/3z/wallhaven-3zgz2y.png" />

      </div>
      <div class="channel-container" style="background-color: lavender;">
        SPOT 2
      </div>
      <div class="channel-container" style="background-color: lightcoral;">
        SPOT 3
      </div>
      <div class="channel-container" style="background-color: lightseagreen;">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/favicon.ico" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-controls">
      common controls and other info goes here
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: If you notice, your fix stole space from the red box at the bottom `.container-controls`, can you adjust for that?

Comment: It is because  the fixed height you are setting on `.parent-trap`.  Remove it, or adjust it and it will work.

Comment: the whole problem is I need the videos to fit the space as is, inside constraints of parent-trap

Comment: if you add this button `<button onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('video-player')[0].requestFullscreen()">Fullscreen</button>` you can see that fullscreen does not work when the images/videos do not properly fit